# Count history records

Tags: sql

I have jobnumber, startdateofjob,enddateofjob in SQL table.
If there is '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' in enddateofjob column, this means it is active job. Other inactive job.
I have data for last two years.

This is currently I am using
Select jobnumber, startdateofjob,enddateofjob
--'Australia' as Country--,STARTDT,ACTEND
--into #Temp
from JOB
where  (enddateofjob = '1900-01-01' OR enddateofjob >=  GETDATE())

How I can find out no of active jobs on certain date(History date) , I need to make this dynamic.
Like
On date                     Active jobs
2021-12-28 00:00:00.000     10 (where enddateofjob ='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')

2021-12-27 00:00:00.000     5 (where enddateofjob ='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
2021-12-26 00:00:00.000     8 (where enddateofjob ='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')

so on ...

Comment: This is a little hard to understand. Can you put your query in a code block please and show and example of the output you're after. cheers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use groupby and count to get the date and no of active jobs

[An example](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php)